# How do implicit conversions work in Scala?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

And more specifically how does the [BigInt](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_7_7_final/src/library/scala/BigInt.scala?view=markup) works for convert int to BigInt?

In the source code it reads:

```
...
implicit def int2bigInt(i: Int): BigInt = apply(i)
...
```

How is this code invoked?

I can understand how this other sample: ["Date literals"](http://paste.pocoo.org/show/211110/) works.

In.

```
val christmas = 24 Dec 2010
```

Defined by:

```
implicit def dateLiterals(date: Int) = new {
  import java.util.Date  
  def Dec(year: Int) = new Date(year, 11, date)
}
```

When `int` get's passed the message `Dec` with an `int` as parameter, the system looks for another method that can handle the request, in this case `Dec(year:Int)`

Q1. Am I right in my understanding of Date literals?

Q2. How does it apply to BigInt?

Comment: I think you're referring to implicit conversions. Implicit parameters are a slightly different thing.

Comment: [Programming in Scala 1st Edition](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/): [Implicit Conversions and Parameters](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/implicit-conversions-and-parameters.html)

Answer (score 17):

When a the provided type doesn't match the expected type, the Scala compiler looks for any method in scope marked implicit that takes the provided type as parameter and returns the expected type as a result. If found, it inserts the call to the method in between.
In the BigInt case, say you have a method

```
doSomethingWithBigInt(d:BigInt)=....
```

And you call it with an integer:

```
doSomethingWithBigInt(10)
```

As the types don't match, the Scala compiler will generate:

```
doSomethingWithBigInt(int2bigInt(10))
```

Assuming the implicit int2bigInt is in scope

Comment: To clarify, it uses an implicit *if it will make code that wouldn't otherwise compile do so*, not just if there's an implicit that accepts the found type as its argument.

Comment: The scope thingy is a red herring. Scala will search for such implicits in the companion object of the original class, and in the companion object of the destination class if that destination class has been inferred. In this case, since the destination class is explicitly BigInt, then BigInt's object companion will be searched for implicits.

Comment: I didn't want to go into details about the scope :)

Comment: @Daniel: In this case the scope is, as you say, not a problem. But should the OP wish to go and implement some implicit conversions of their own I'd have to agree with @GClaramunt that it's worth mentioning briefly at least.

Answer (score 14):

The point of implicit stuff is to fill in boring boilerplate stuff when there is clearly only one right way to do it.

In the case of *implicit parameters* the compiler inserts a parameter from context that must be what you were thinking of.  For example,

```
case class TaxRate(rate: BigDecimal) { }
implicit var sales_tax = TaxRate(0.075)
def withTax(price: BigDecimal)(implicit tax: TaxRate) = price*(tax.rate+1)

scala> withTax(15.00)
res0: scala.math.BigDecimal = 16.1250
```

Since we've marked the tax rate as an implicit parameter, and provided an implicit variable that can be filled in when needed, we don't need to specify the tax rate.  The compiler automatically fills in `withTax(15.00)(sales_tax)`

In the case of *implicit conversions*, the compiler looks for a method that can take a type that it has and convert it to the type that is needed.  This conversion cannot be chained under normal circumstances, so you have to get to what you need in *one* step.

There are two cases where implicit conversions are likely to come into play.  One is in the *parameter* of a method call--if the type is wrong, but it can be converted to the right type (in exactly one way), then the compiler will convert for you.  The other is in the *presence* of a method call--if the type actually used doesn't have the method available, but you could convert it to a type that does have that method, then the conversion will take place and then the method will be called.

Let's look at an example of each.

```
implicit def float2taxrate(f: Float) = TaxRate(BigDecimal(f))
scala> withTax(15.00)(0.15f)
res1: scala.math.BigDecimal = 17.250000089406967200
```

Here, we call an explicit tax rate of `0.15f`.  That doesn't match the parameter, which must be of type `TaxRate`, but the compiler sees that we can turn floats into tax rates using the implicit `float2taxrate`.  So it does it for us, calling `withTax(15.00)(float2taxrate(0.15f))`

Now the other example.

```
class Currency(bd: BigDecimal) {
  def rounded = bd.setScale(2,BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)
}
implicit def bigdec2currency(bd: BigDecimal) = new Currency(bd)
scala> withTax(15.00)(0.15f).rounded
res66: scala.math.BigDecimal = 17.25
```

BigDecimal doesn't have a `rounded` method, so `withTax(15.00)(0.15f)` shouldn't be able to call one (as it returns a `BigDecimal`).  But we've defined a `Currency` that does have a `rounded` method, and a conversion to `Currency`, so the implicit conversion fills in all the details: `bigdec2currency(withTax(15.00)(0.15f)).rounded`.

In the case of the conversion from `Int` to `BigInt`, the compiler will use it when, for example, it tries to add `7 + BigInt(5)`.  This isn't going to work normally--`7` is an `Int` and `Int` doesn't know how to add itself to `BigInt`.  But `BigInt` has a method `+` that can add itself to another `BigInt`.  And the compiler sees that if only it could convert `7` to a `BigInt`, it could use that method.  The implicit conversion allows that conversion, so it translates `7 + BigInt(5)` into `int2bigInt(7)+BigInt(5)`.

(Note: `int2bigInt` is defined inside `BigInt`, so to use it you have to `import BigInt._`.  And it in turn defers to the `apply(i: Int)` method of the `BigInt` object, which is what lets you write `BigInt(5)` and have it work (rather than having to pass a string as with `BigInteger` in Java).)

Answer (score 2):

Complementing @GClaramunt's answer.

Because it's way simpler to understand and grasp this concept by seeing a full example:

```
// define a class
case class Person(firstName: String, lastName: String)

// must import this to enable implicit conversions
import scala.language.implicitConversions

// define the implicit conversion. String to Person in this case
implicit def stringToPerson(name:String) = {
  val fields = name.split(" ");
  Person(fields(0), fields(1))
}

// method using the implicit conversion  
def getPerson(fullName:String): Person = fullName

val fooBar = getPerson("foo bar")
println(fooBar.getClass())  // class Person
println(fooBar.firstName)  // foo
println(fooBar.lastName)  // bar
```

I hope this example clarifies why and how one would want to use implicit conversions (not that I think converting `String` to `Person` makes a lot of sense but it's worth the illustration).