# How does Scala java conversion work?

Tags: scala, scala-java-interop

If I have java.util.List and want to iterate over it user Scala syntax I import :

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
```

and the java.util.List is implicitly converted to scala.collection.mutable.Set

(http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.JavaConversions%24)

But how is this conversion achieved ? I'm confused as this is the first time I've encountered the ability to convert an object type by just importing a package.

Comment: The source is linked straight from that page; start there. https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.2/src/library/scala/collection/JavaConversions.scala

Comment: Aside: you might find `JavaConverters` preferable since it requires the use of the `asScala` method, hence avoiding invisible implicit conversion magic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JavaConversions` object contains many implicit conversions between Scala->Java and Java->Scala collections. When you import all members of `JavaConversions`, all of those conversions are put in the current scope, and are therefore evaluated when an immediate collection type isn't available.

For example, when Scala compiler is looking for a collection of type `X` and cannot find it, it will also try to find a collection of type `Y` and an implicit conversion `Y to X` in scope.

To understand more about how the conversions are evaluated, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2861739/196068) answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a pattern "Pimp my library" that allows to "add" methods to any existing class. See for instance [the answer of Daniel C. Sobral](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4467012/2646454), http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=179766, or [google](http://google.com/?q=pimp+my+library+pattern+scala) other examples.

In short: an implicit method returns a wrapper with the desired methods:

```
implicit def enrichString(s:String) = new EnrichedString(s)
class EnrichedString(s:String){
  def hello = "Hello, "+s
}

assert("World".hello === "Hello, World")
```

It can also be shortened with sugar:

```
implicit class EnrichedString(s:String){
  def hello = "Hello, "+s
}
```